# Indexing numpy array by a numpy array of coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, idioms

Suppose we have

- an n-dimensional numpy.array A
- a numpy.array B with dtype=int and shape of (n, m)

How do I index A by B so that the result is an array of shape (m,), with values taken from the positions indicated by the columns of B?

For example, consider this code that does what I want when B is a python list:

```
>>> a = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
>>> a[[0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 2]]
array([ 1, 10, 20])    # the result we're after
>>> bl = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 2]]
>>> a[bl]
array([ 1, 10, 20])   # also works when indexing with a python list
>>> a[bl].shape
(3,)
```

However, when B is a numpy array, the result is different:

```
>>> b = np.array(bl)
>>> a[b].shape
(3, 3, 3, 3)
```

Now, I can get the desired result by casting B into a tuple, but surely that cannot be the proper/idiomatic way to do it?

```
>>> a[tuple(b)]
array([ 1, 10, 20])
```

Is there a numpy function to achieve the same without casting B to a tuple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative would be converting to linear indices and then index with `np.take` or index into its flattened version -

```
np.take(a,np.ravel_multi_index(b, a.shape))
a.flat[np.ravel_multi_index(b, a.shape)]
```

**Custom `np.ravel_multi_index` for performance boost**

We could implement a custom version to simulate the behaviour of `np.ravel_multi_index` to boost the performance, like so -

```
def ravel_index(b, shp):
    return np.concatenate((np.asarray(shp[1:])[::-1].cumprod()[::-1],[1])).dot(b)
```

Using it, the desired output would be found in two ways -

```
np.take(a,ravel_index(b, a.shape))
a.flat[ravel_index(b, a.shape)]
```

#### Benchmarking

Additionall incorporating `tuple` based method from the question and `map` based one from @Kanak's post.

Case #1 : dims = 3

```
In [23]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,([20]*3))

In [24]: b = np.random.randint(0,20,(a.ndim,1000000))

In [25]: %timeit a[tuple(b)]
    ...: %timeit a[map(np.ravel, b)]  
    ...: %timeit np.take(a,np.ravel_multi_index(b, a.shape))
    ...: %timeit a.flat[np.ravel_multi_index(b, a.shape)]
    ...: %timeit np.take(a,ravel_index(b, a.shape))
    ...: %timeit a.flat[ravel_index(b, a.shape)]
100 loops, best of 3: 6.56 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6.58 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6.95 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 9.17 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6.31 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 8.52 ms per loop
```

Case #2 : dims = 6

```
In [29]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,([10]*6))

In [30]: b = np.random.randint(0,10,(a.ndim,1000000))

In [31]: %timeit a[tuple(b)]
    ...: %timeit a[map(np.ravel, b)]  
    ...: %timeit np.take(a,np.ravel_multi_index(b, a.shape))
    ...: %timeit a.flat[np.ravel_multi_index(b, a.shape)]
    ...: %timeit np.take(a,ravel_index(b, a.shape))
    ...: %timeit a.flat[ravel_index(b, a.shape)]
10 loops, best of 3: 40.9 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 40 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 20 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 29.9 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 15.7 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 25.8 ms per loop
```

Case #3 : dims = 10

```
In [32]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,([4]*10))

In [33]: b = np.random.randint(0,4,(a.ndim,1000000))

In [34]: %timeit a[tuple(b)]
    ...: %timeit a[map(np.ravel, b)]  
    ...: %timeit np.take(a,np.ravel_multi_index(b, a.shape))
    ...: %timeit a.flat[np.ravel_multi_index(b, a.shape)]
    ...: %timeit np.take(a,ravel_index(b, a.shape))
    ...: %timeit a.flat[ravel_index(b, a.shape)]
10 loops, best of 3: 60.7 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 60.1 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 27.8 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 38 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 18.7 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 29.3 ms per loop
```

So, it makes sense to look for alternatives when working with higher-dimensional inputs and with large data.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that fits your need involves the use of [`np.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html)

```
>>> a[map(np.ravel, b)]
array([ 1, 10, 20])
```

However not fully [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/)-based.

---

***Performance-concerns.***
*Updated following the comments below.*

Be that as it may, your approach is better than mine, but not better than any of @Divakar's.

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

a = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
bl = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 2]]
b = np.array(bl)

imps = "from __main__ import np,a,b"
reps = 100000

tup_cas_t = timeit.Timer("a[tuple(b)]", imps).timeit(reps)
map_rav_t = timeit.Timer("a[map(np.ravel, b)]", imps).timeit(reps)
fla_rp1_t = timeit.Timer("np.take(a,np.ravel_multi_index(b, a.shape))", imps).timeit(reps)
fla_rp2_t = timeit.Timer("a.flat[np.ravel_multi_index(b, a.shape)]", imps).timeit(reps)

print tup_cas_t/map_rav_t  ## 0.505382211881
print tup_cas_t/fla_rp1_t  ## 1.18185817386
print tup_cas_t/fla_rp2_t  ## 1.71288705886
```

Comment: Well `flat` and `np.take` are two separate alternatives.

Comment: @Divakar. Sorry. Blind copy-pasting, one of our worst enemy.

Comment: Also, I would rather use `%timeit` when dealing with such tiny fractioned timings. You don't need to do those, I am just saying for a fair benchmarking that is. Again, OP seems to be going for a idiomatic way. Personal opinion - `tuple` isn't too bad either way.

Comment: Good to know @Divakar. That being said, don't you think that 100000 repetitions ensures a minimum of benchmark-fairness? Also, `%timeit` is an [IPython](http://ipython.org/)'s feature/magic, isn't it ? If so, I do not use iPython. I have actually no reason for not doing so.

Comment: Fair enough. How about something bigger, like let's say : `a = np.random.randint(0,9,(10,10,10,10,10,10)); b = np.random.randint(0,10,(6,10000))`?

Comment: @Divakar I would play with hypo-versions of `a` and `b` and then infer performance-concerns using time-complexity considerations/calculations. Won't you?

Comment: Added some timings with large data and dims in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [`numpy.ndarray.tolist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) ?

```
>>> a = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
>>> bl = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 2]]
>>> b = np.array(bl)
>>> a[b.tolist()]
array([ 1, 10, 20])
```

Or for [arrays indexing arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays) which is quite similar to list indexing :

```
>>> a[np.array([0, 1, 2]), np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([1, 1, 2])]
array([ 1, 10, 20])
```

However as you can from the previous link, indexing an array a with an array b directly means you are indexing the first index of a only with your whole b array which can lead to confusing output.